# ¿Cómo pasar un programa a segundo plano?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Me gustaría pasar a segundo plano un programa que tengo en la carpeta de inicio, para que se ejecute al iniciar sesión en windows.
He probado a usar el programa nircmd pero no veo la forma en la que lo puedo hacer. Además cuando pongo: `Nircmd win hide ititle "programa""` en el cmd de windows me sale un mensaje que me dice que Nircmd no es una aplicación win32 válida. La verdad es que no he encontrado prácticamente nada en [su web](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).
De paso ya pregunto si hay algo que se pueda hacer en este sentido con Python.

SO: WXP SP3

Python: 3.4.4

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y feliz año.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usa un .vbs para que haga esto, cambia la ruta de auto-inicio por el de .vbs y se iniciara en modo oculto.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "C:\myprograma.exe", 0, True
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la ruta de .vbs? Yo he abierto el cmd de windows y he escrito lo que me has puesto tu (con las rutas adaptadas a mi programa), y aparentemente no he tenido ningún error, pero al reiniciar el ordenador no he observado que mi programa haya pasado a segundo plano.

Comment: Ahora lo estoy escribiendo en el cmd  y me da un error: `"objShell.Run" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable`

Comment: No, es cmd es wscript o sea crea un archivo nuevo (startprograma.vbs) ahi pones el codigo y cambia la ruta de la linea 2 y pones la del programa que quieres abrir ¿Que usas para abrir automáticamente? me imagino que el registro de Windows entonces pones en la ruta el archivo _startprograma.vbs_.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es hacerlo con powershell que es soportado en cmd por defecto.

```
@echo off
set "rutadearchivo=C:\Users\Yo\archivo ejecutable.extensión"
powershell start -FilePath '"%rutadearchivo%"' -WindowStyle hidden
```

Si deseas heredar los parámetros del script hacia el archivo ejecutable puedes hacer algo así

```
@echo off
if "%*" NEQ "" set "parametros=-ArgumentList '%*'"
set "rutadearchivo=C:\Users\Yo\archivo ejecutable.extensión"
powershell start -FilePath '"%rutadearchivo%"' %parametros% -WindowStyle hidden
```

FilePath es la ruta del archivo a ejecutar, WindowStyle es para especificar el modo de ventana (hidden, maximized, minimized y normal), por último la variable "parametros" agrega el parámetro ArgumentList (lista de argumentos) al comando de powershell para heredar (si es que hay) todos los argumentos del archivo bat al archivo ejecutado